# Setting value to an existing column for all the rows that have null value on that column

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to update and set a certain value for a column IF it's value is `null`?

For example:
I have 10 rows in the table `Products`. I want to set the value `'0'` for all the rows to a column called `quantity` IF that row has value `null` on that particular column.

I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE Products ADD DEFAULT '0' FOR quantity
WITH VALUES;
```

...but it didn't update the `null` values to `0` on that column.

Comment: For existing rows: `Update Products set quantity = 0 where quantity IS NULL`

Comment: You need an UPDATE to update existing rows.

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader, thanks. That worked.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` can handle the future entries for the `quantity` column. If you want to focus about the existing columns you need `UPDATE`

Comment: @SteveWaters Glad to help you.

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader, if you write it as the answer I'll check it green. Someone else answered but you commented the right answer before that.

Comment: @SteveWaters I am so Hungry of reputation points, cannot refuse the offer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Alter Table` is effecting the new rows.

For existing rows use the following code:-

```
Update Products set quantity = 0 where quantity IS NULL.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `WITH VALUES` clause applies when you add a column, not when you alter an existing one. This explains why the rows still contain NULL in the altered column.

And as the column is still nullable (you haven't added a NOT NULL constraint), the nulls are perfectly valid (and there is no reason for the DBMS to change these NULLS to the default value). You can of course explicitly update all existing NULLs:

```
update products set quantity = 0 where quantity is null;
```

but you can later add records with a NULL quantity again. So you may want to update the records first and then alter the column so as to forbid NULLs at all:

```
alter table products alter column quantity integer not null;
```

Comment: This was a great answer. I wondered earlier why my default values don't appear to the rows but it was because null was allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
  update Products
  set quantity=0
  where quantity is null
```